# How do I take a square slice of an image and convert it to a circle in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

After reading this blog post about converting a square slice of a map into a 2D circle to simulate a spinning globe, I thought I'd give it a go. The author claims to have made a version of his program in pygame where he colours each pixel individually.

http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/blog/spinning-globe

I gave it a try and it takes about ten minutes to generate a single image of a 100 pixel radius circle, never mind the number of images necessary to simulate a spinning globe. The way I'm doing it is obviously rubbish, since I've encountered this problem when trying to generate images of gradient noise and when scanning webcam input, but I have no idea how to "colour each pixel individually" without writing a program that iterates through each pixel, checking for a condition and assigning a numeric value. Iterating through every pixel is obviously resource consuming, even if it's a surfarray and not a Surface.

My function looks something like this, taking an alpha array that forms the circle shape, followed by a surfarray of the sliced part of the map I would like to display in the circle.

```
def draw_globe(alpha_array, world_slice):
    rgb_array = alpha_array 
    for x in range(len(alpha_array)):
        print x
        for y in range(len(alpha_array[x])):
            if alpha_array[x][y] == 0:
                rgb_array[x,y] = BLACK
            else:
                for point in range(len(world_slice[:, y])):
                    if world_slice[point][ y] == MAP_BLUE:
                        colour = TRUE_BLUE
                    else:
                        colour = TRUE_GREEN
                    rgb_array[get_x_coord(y, point, 100), y] = colour
    return pygame.surfarray.make_surface(rgb_array)
```

I was just taking a stab in the dark at it, but I'm stumped by how to make it faster. Is it really possible to make a working pygame version of this program that colours every pixel individually, like the author claims, or is there a smarter, faster way to do it via transforming or warping the map image itself into a circle?

Comment: You could probably do it much faster by using [texture-mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping). This can [apparently](http://www.pygame.org/project-Map+Editor-455-781.html) be done by using PyOpenGL along with PyGame. That said, your example code could be sped-up considerably by pre-computing the mapping of coordinates from one space to another.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the suggestion about pre-computing the coordinates, but that doesn't seem to have sped up the program in any measureable way. I've been watching it run for about 10 minutes now, still choking on a single frame.
I'll try checking out PyOpenGL's texture-mapping capabilities. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You should try profiling your code to see exactly where it's spending its time.